# Bash: Put a job in the background and then tail the log

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, background-process

How do you make the escaping work so that the `&` is actually running the first command in the background?

```
# foo param1 param2 >> run.out &; tail -f run.out
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just drop the semicolon:

```
# foo param1 param2 >> run.out & tail -f run.out
```

Comment: It helps to think of the ampersand as a *variant* of the semicolon, which it is, really.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the backgrounded command in ()'s.

```
(ls -R / >>/tmp/list & ); tail -f /tmp/list
```

Sadly, this really backgrounds it.  You won't be able to us %1 to get to its PID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nohup:

```
nohup cmd & 

tail -f nohup.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this question as well, and solved it this way:

```
`foo param1 param2 >> run.out &` ; tail -f run.out
```

I don't know if the semantics are different.

For this specific case, the following is also useful:

```
foo param1 param2 | tee -a run.out
```